# How to use Register-Objectevent to invoke a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, event-handling, powershell-2.0

I was trying to execute powershell in parallel mode. I was advised to create an event which will trigger whenever there is a change in folder.

For ex: If a folder name called "test1" is created in a particular folder then my powershell script test1.ps1 should be triggered.

I was trying to get example for this with Register-Objevent , but i am not getting any good clue.

If you have implemented some thing like this , can you please guide me?

---

Updated:

When i create a file named test1.ps1 in the "D:\ParallelEvent\temp" folder, it should execute test1.ps1 powershell file. Following is the code for that

```
 $ScriptLoc="D:\My_Scripts"
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{Path = 'D:\ParallelEvent\temp';Filter = '*.txt';NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'}
    $CreatedAction =
    {
    $FilenamewithoutExtn=$(($event.sourceEventArgs.Name).Split('.')[0])
    Start-Job $ScriptLoc\$FilenamewithoutExtn.ps1
    Get-Job -State Running | Wait-Job
    } 

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $CreatedAction
```

My test1.ps1 has following line

```
[system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("Hello, Test1!")
```

But still it doesn't execute the test1.ps1 it seems. I did not get any messagebox. Am i missing any thing?

Answer (score 1):

you are not getting messagebox because powershell jobs run as background process and does not show ui.

if you modify the test1.ps1 to a file redirection

```
"test " > C:\AnywhereYouWantToRedirectData\testagain.txt
```

you will be able to see that the test1.ps1 runs and redirected file gets created (testagain.txt).